# Flash mobile application build error ios

Tags: ios, flash-builder

I am getting following error while running application in iOS device, application runs fine on simulator. Flash builder 4.7, SDK 4.6, iPhone simulator SDK 7.1....

Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x9 rip=0x117353723
/var/folders/1f/gbfkl25x0fz7ds3z3cfpss000000gn/T/cmd3243169928935192791.tmp: line 1:  1192 Segmentation fault: 11  "java" "-Xss1500K" "-Xms256m" "-Xmx3072m" "-cp" "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0/lib/adt.jar" "com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator" "/Users/riteshkohad/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/Chart/bin-debug/AOT/AOTBuildOutput3050130756550019736.tmp/BitcodeGenerator_opts.ser" "/Users/riteshkohad/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/Chart/bin-debug/AOT/AOTBuildOutput3050130756550019736.tmp/ABCFiles"
Compilation failed while executing : ADT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..... In my case, I had to reconfigure Flash Builder 4.7 with latest AIR SDK, manually replacing each existing AIR SDK file with new one.....

Hope this will help someone!!